# How to pass an object from a java class to servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache's HttpClient to call a servlet from a Java class. I want to send an object to the servlet which should save the object using Serialization. How to send the object to the servlet?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Names names = new Names();
        names.setName("ABC");
        names.setPlace("Bangalore");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9080/HttpClientPractice/FirstServlet");
//Rest of the code
```

In the above code snippet, I have another class Names and I want to send an object of Names to the servlet. Right now I am only calling the servlet with the URI, but I want to pass the object.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to look into the POST method to send data like that. I believe with GET method, you can send only textual data.

Comment: @silverback POST method it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to a Json String using a Library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in the class you have shown and add this string as a query parameter - showing you how to do it with Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(names);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9080/HttpClientPractice/FirstServlet?obj="+json);
```

In the class you are going to store this object, do a fromJson (method in the Gson library)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Names names = fromJson(json, Names.class);
```

Comment: Got it! I used 'HttpPost()' instead of 'HttpGet()' and sent the string **json** as a value of a key-value pair.

Comment: I am getting a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson** for the line `Gson gson = new Gson()`. Any idea why that could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to send the object to a URL is send it either as XML or JSON instead of serializing object and sending it.

One way to send the object if your method remains the same is to attach the object values in url as query string e.g: 

`http://localhost:9080/HttpClientPractice/FirstServlet?name=ABC&place=Banglore` 

The other way would be to change the request method to POST and send object as XML or JSON content.

Comment: Thanks, got your point. But one clarification. I want the servlet to serialize the object that I send, I don't want to send a serialized object.

Comment: @Rajath So, you want a pony. In order to send an object over network, you have to serialize it. There's no other way in Java. It may be called "marshalling", "encoding", whatever, still, there's serialization somewhere underneath.