# HTML5 server sent events+Java Servlets - Sending a data with multiple values inside an Object

Tags: java, html, servlets, server-sent-events

I'm working with HTML5 server-sent events with Java servlets.Till date i've achieved only passing the string from server.

For a single value to write, I code like

```
data: myvalue
```

To pass set of values, I can do like below

```
data: {"username": "Mike", "time": "02:34:11", "text": "Hi Mike."}
```

But I do want to know like is there anyway I can pass a Java Model object (values for variables are stored by setter methods) into the data stream of Server-sent events.

So that in my script, I can access those values.

Anyone suggest me a correct way to do this..

Comment: use JSON for this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to use a Json object using `toJson(Object src)` to write in a Json object and `fromJson(Reader json, Class<T> classOfT)` to read from this object.

See the [Class Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) for more details.

And take a look at [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776516/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-java-class-to-servlet).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.. Add the model object into JSON object and write as a string in the stream. In Script, simply parse the event data and get the values.